# Calculate the increase in new positive cases in SQL

Tags: mysql

Currently I have a table called test:

| id | test_date | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-11-25 | positive |
| 2 | 2021-11-25 | positive |
| 3 | 2021-11-25 | positive |
| 4 | 2021-11-26 | negative |
| 5 | 2021-11-26 | positive |

How could I get the increase in new positive cases on 2021-11-26 compared to 2021-11-25. The result should show a single number indicating the increment. If there are few new positive cases than yesterday, this number should be negative.

Expected results:

| increment |
| --- |
| -2 |

explanation: 1 - 3 = -2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

```
SELECT SUM(test_date = '2021-11-26') - SUM(test_date = '2021-11-25') AS increment
FROM table
WHERE test_date IN ('2021-11-25', '2021-11-26')
  AND result = 'positive'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below dynamic query, where you do not need to specify dates, you can simply use current date() and date_diff of current_date() and 1:

```
select(
select count(result)  from test where result = 'positive' and test_date = current_date())
-
(select count(result)  from test where result = 'positive' and test_date =DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as increment
```

Result:

```
increment
-2
```